# getting part from page source python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a specific part from a page using regex but it isn't working.

This is the part I want to be extracted from the page:

```
"publishedTimeText":{"runs":[{"text":"1 day ago","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CLQBEPS8AiITCPGhkIPt094CFc8SKgodd30BJSibHA==","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/community?lb=Ugy4VG4gQFILnreq-Bd4AaABCQ","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE"}}
```

So far I've tried this :

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://rophoto.es/kha.txt')


mystrx = re.search(r'^{"publishedTimeText":.*"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE"}}', html_source)
```

but it didn't work out for me.

Comment: Try it removing the `{` in `^{`

Answer (score 0):

How about this code:

```
import requests
import re

regex = r"\"publishedTimeText\":.*?\"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE\"}}"
r = requests.get('http://rophoto.es/kha.txt')
html_source = r.content.decode('utf-8')

mystrx = re.search(regex, html_source, re.MULTILINE)
print(mystrx.group(0))
# "publishedTimeText":{"runs":[{"text":"1 day ago","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CLQBEPS8AiITCPGhkIPt094CFc8SKgodd30BJSibHA==","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/community?lb=Ugy4VG4gQFILnreq-Bd4AaABCQ","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE"}}
```

Details at regex101: https://regex101.com/r/WJ82Ky/1

With this link: `https://youtube.com/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/community` you need:
– pip install selenium
– pip install webdriver_manager
Then use follow code, it works fine on my computer:

```
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

regex = r"\"publishedTimeText\":.*?\"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE\"}}"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://youtube.com/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/community')
html_source = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

mystrx = re.search(regex, html_source, re.MULTILINE)
print(mystrx.group(0))
# "publishedTimeText":{"runs":[{"text":"2 days ago","navigationEndpoint":{"clickTrackingParams":"CLQBEPS8AiITCKisjoWO1t4CFVwlKgodcY4PXiibHA==","commandMetadata":{"webCommandMetadata":{"url":"/channel/UCqwUrj10mAEsqezcItqvwEw/community?lb=Ugy4VG4gQFILnreq-Bd4AaABCQ","webPageType":"WEB_PAGE_TYPE_BROWSE"}}
```

Comment: Because youtube url is structured different with  rophoto url. It hasn't data like `"publishedTimeText":{"runs"...`

Comment: but it works when i view the page source in chrome , and copy paste the source to rophoto

Comment: i also used chrome useragent in request for youtube url , still doesnt work

Comment: can u please help ?

Comment: I add more a solution for the youtube link! See my updated post!

Comment: if i wanted to do it with chrome webdriver i could've done it, thing is i dont want to use chrome webdriver, anyways thanks for your answer